# Webview scrolling weird behavior

Tags: android

I have a webview with a bunch of images in it stacked vertically. When I run it on a nexus 6 emulator the scrolling works how I'd expect from my web-browsing on my phone.

However when I deploy the APK to my actual device, the scrolling behaves totally differently. It lags a bit behind my finger, and seems to have no inertia at all. This is on a Samsung s8+.

This is my current configuration:

```
      String html = "<html><head><style>body {margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;} img {}</style><body>" + imagesHTML + "</body></html>";
        String mime = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";

        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
//        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        webView.setInitialScale(100);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Overflow: hidden; on the body was causing the weird behavior.